# How to create and access structure which structure corresponds to given variable list in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to create a structure to store the data from the database.

I created a function

```
function result = LoadDataFromDB(query, columnNames)
```

where column names represents the list of column names, for example {'id', 'year', 'name'...}

After executing the following query

```
ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

I would like to fill the structure, but haven't figured out how to dynamically access the fields in the structure.

Here is the code piece that should create and fill the structure:

```
varnamelist = genvarname(columnNames);

result = cell2struct(cell(size(varnamelist(:))), varnamelist(:));
while rs.next()
    count=count+1;
    for i = 1 : length(columnNames)
        fieldname = columnNames(i);
        value = char(rs.getString(i));
          %result(count).columnNames(i)=char(rs.getString(i));
          result(count).(fieldname) = value;
    end
end
```

The main problem is the line

```
result(count).(fieldname) = value;
```

To describe a problem below is the copy from the console output:

```
K>> result(1)

ans = 

    a: []
    b: []
    c: []

K>> result(1).('a')

ans =

     []

K>> fieldname

fieldname = 

    'a'
```

Concluding from the above output, the command result(1).(fieldname) should access the field 'a' but trying it out, it returns the following error:

```
K>> result(1).(fieldname)
??? Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.
```

Does anyone know how to fill the structure dinamically?

Comment: Try `fieldname = columnNames{i};`, i.e., are you sure that it's a regular string array, or is it a cell-array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's dynamic field reference. You can find more on it [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) for example.

Dynamic reference can be used to assign or reference fields in structures like so:

```
fieldName = 'some_field';
your_struct.(fieldName) = fieldValue
```

So, in your case, that would mean modifying the inner loop body to

```
fieldname = columnNames{i};
value = rs.getString{i};
result(count).(fieldname) = value;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for, but don't know what causes the error. I modified the code above so it might be more cleare where the main problem is.

Comment: @NikoGamulin Try `fieldname = columnNames{i};`, i.e., are you sure that it's a regular string array, or is it a cell-array?

Comment: @NikoGamulin I think using `value = rs.getString{i};` instead of casting to char will be faster; give it a try.